# How to get the registered user Notification API data come for guest user too?

Tags: ios, swift, api, web-services

**Current Scenario?**:
Th registered user of the book app gets the notifications such as 'books available for download', q&A portal answers, live streaming link.

**What is the goal?**:
To get the notifications for guest where it can show the available books for download, and other notification that comes for registered user.

**What is the issue/errors?**:
When user clicks on the notification button , nothing comes on the screen. Everything blank and no notification is shown. It show the below error::
[image]

**What i tried?**:
When we call API, the token is generated from the backend. This token is then used to get the access.  I tried to copy the API method to the home-screen that is used from 'signUpVC'(sign up view controller) to get the token bit showing above error.

Admin user notification looks as below:
[image]

Guest user (notification from our android app)
[image]

**Code:** for SignUp

```js
import UIKit
import PKHUD
import SDWebImage

class SignupVC: ThemeController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imgProfile: TappableImageView!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblRegister: UILabel!
    
    
    var isFromUpdateProfile = Bool()
    
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // MARK: - Class Properties
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFirstName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtLastName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtCity: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // MARK: - Memory Management Functions
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    deinit {
        
    }
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // MARK: - Class Functions
    
    private func errorsInTextFields() -> String? {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        
        guard !txtFirstName.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankFirstName }
        guard txtFirstName.hasValid(.alphabetWithSpace) else { return UserMessages.kValidFirstName }
        
        guard !txtLastName.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankLastName }
        guard txtLastName.hasValid(.alphabetWithSpace) else { return UserMessages.kValidLastName }
        
        guard !txtEmail.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankEmail }
        guard txtEmail.hasValid(.email) else { return UserMessages.kValidEmail }
        
        guard !txtCity.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankCity }
        guard txtCity.hasValid(.alphabetWithSpace) else { return UserMessages.kValidCity }
        
        guard !txtPassword.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankPassword }
        //guard txtPassword.hasValid(.password) else { return UserMessages.kValidPassword }
        
        // No Errors
        return nil
    }
    
    private func errorsInEditProfileTextFields() -> String? {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        
        guard !txtFirstName.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankFirstName }
        guard txtFirstName.hasValid(.alphabetWithSpace) else { return UserMessages.kValidFirstName }
        
        guard !txtLastName.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankLastName }
        guard txtLastName.hasValid(.alphabetWithSpace) else { return UserMessages.kValidLastName }
        
        guard !txtEmail.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankEmail }
        guard txtEmail.hasValid(.email) else { return UserMessages.kValidEmail }
        
        guard !txtCity.isEmpty else { return UserMessages.kBlankCity }
        guard txtCity.hasValid(.alphabetWithSpace) else { return UserMessages.kValidCity }
        
        // No Errors
        return nil
    }
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // MARK: - Action Functions
    
    @IBAction func btnRegisterAction(_ sender: RoundButton) {
        if let _ = User.current?.accessToken{
            //TextField Verification
            if let error = errorsInEditProfileTextFields() {
                SnackBar.show(error)
                return
            }
            //API Calling
            self.apiEditProfileCall()
        }else{
            //TextField Verification
            if let error = errorsInTextFields() {
                SnackBar.show(error)
                return
            }
            //API Calling
            apiRegisterDeviceCall()
        }
    }
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // MARK: - Web Service Functions
    
    private func apiRegisterDeviceCall() {
        
        HUD.show(.progress)
        var deviceToken:String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DeviceToken") ?? "empty"
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "vDeviceUniqueId"   : DeviceManager.deviceUniqueId,
            "txDeviceToken"     : deviceToken,
            "tDeviceOs"         : DeviceManager.deviceOS,
            "vDeviceName"       : DeviceManager.modelName,
            "vResolution"       : DeviceManager.resolution,
            "vOsVersion"        : DeviceManager.osVersion,
        ]
        
        print(parameters)
        
        APIManager.shared.makeRequest(method: .registerDevice, parameters: parameters, withLoader: false) { (response, error) in
            print(response)
            if let accessToken = response["data"]["access_token"].string {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(accessToken, forKey: "AccessToken")
                self.apiRegisterCall()
            } else {
                HUD.hide()
                SnackBar.show("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func apiRegisterCall() {
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "vFirstName"    : txtFirstName.trimmedText,
            "vLastName"     : txtLastName.trimmedText,
            "vEmail"        : txtEmail.trimmedText,
            "vPassword"     : txtPassword.trimmedText,
            "vCityName"     : txtCity.trimmedText,
        ]
        
        var images: [String: UIImage] = [:]
        
        if let image = imgProfile.image {
            images["txProfileImageUrl"] = image
        }
        
        APIManager.shared.makeRequest(method: .registerUser, parameters: parameters, imageParameters: images, withLoader: false) { (response, error) in
            
            HUD.hide()
            
            if response["data"].exists() {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    self.popViewController()
                }
                
//                Alert.showWith("User Registered", message: "Please check your email inbox for varification email", positiveTitle: "Ok", shouldResignOnTouchOutside: false) { isOk in
//                    if isOk {
//                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
//                            self.popViewController()
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
            } else {
                SnackBar.show(response["message"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func apiEditProfileCall() {
        
        HUD.show(.progress)
        
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "vFirstName"    : txtFirstName.trimmedText,
            "vLastName"     : txtLastName.trimmedText,
            "vEmail"        : txtEmail.trimmedText,
            "vCityName"     : txtCity.trimmedText,
        ]
        
        var images: [String: UIImage] = [:]
        
        if let image = imgProfile.image {
            images["txProfileImageUrl"] = image
        }
        
        APIManager.shared.makeRequest(method: .editProfile, parameters: parameters, imageParameters: images, withLoader: false) { (response, error) in
            
            HUD.hide()
            
            if response["data"].exists(){
                if let accessToken = User.current?.accessToken{
                    var updateUser = User(withJSON: response["data"])
                    updateUser.accessToken = accessToken
                    User.current = updateUser
                    SnackBar.show("Profile successfully updated.")
                    self.navigationController?.popViewControllers(viewsToPop: 2)
                }
            }else{
                SnackBar.show(response["message"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    // MARK: - Life Cycle Functions
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        if let _ = User.current?.accessToken{
            self.passwordView.isHidden = true
            self.lblRegister.text = "Update"
            self.title = "Edit Profile"
            
            self.imgProfile.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray
            self.imgProfile.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:  User.current!.profileImage), placeholderImage: nil)
            
            self.txtFirstName.text = User.current!.firstName
            self.txtLastName.text = User.current!.lastName
            self.txtEmail.text = User.current!.email
            self.txtCity.text = User.current!.cityName
        }
    }
    
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Comment: This seems to be more of an issue with the backend than with swift ?

Comment: currently, admin users and Master users are able to receive book data in the notification. Can't we just use the same API call for the guest too as it doesn't have much difference?

Comment: Who is developing the backend ? I think the question you asked should be to them. One small difference can call an API to not function normally. Plus I do not see any code related to what is done differently between a guest user and registered user. It might be better to post the differences upfront than your whole view controller code.

Comment: the only difference between the registered and admin user is that . admin user can see more books which are yet to be available for registered/guest user. i added the image how the guest user is supposed(image from our android app) to see the notification. currently only limited  notifications come

Comment: Who is developing the backend and is there a way for me to call this API / reproduce what you are doing ?

Comment: It looks like a simple network error. The device was unable to find the IP address for that dns name. Check your DNS and network settings